# How to Highlight Top Three Data on DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Beginner question. So, i have project on VB.Net, where i **need to highlight top three row** in DataGridView (by the highest value). How can i do that?

In this program i'm not using database to store the value, because everything is generated, show in the DataGridView and then get highlighted (What i expected).

**Rule (Pseudocode)**

```
If (column="WASPAS")>6.69 then 
    If(row>3) Then Highlight 3 Rows
    ElseIf(row<3) Then Highlight the Rest of Rows
End If
```

**Mycode right now:**

```
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvWASPAS.Rows
        If row.Cells(9).Value > 0.69 Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
        Next
```

My data type is Double. Here, i attach my DataGridView lookslike
[DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L46Nh.png)

Please help me, i got stuck here for few days. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question text and the accompanying code, do not appear to match. In the text it appears you want the three highest values in a column to be highlighted with a different color. Yet the code, appears to highlight all the rows that are greater than a supplied value. These are two different things; can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: It is unclear if your posted code works. The code appears correct ignoring a possible implicit cast exception. If the cell value is greater than “0.69”, then, that row will be colored green. This bears no resemblance of what you describe you want in the text. If you want the highest three values highlighted, then it should be obvious that you would need to loop through the grid at least once if not more. On solution is to “sort” the data by the value. There are many ways to do this. Have you tried to sort the grid and would this help in coloring the highest X values?

Comment: @JohnG I want to clarify my question. Actually, I want to highlight the 3 highest values in a column in the DataGridView, but that will only happen if the highest value in a column is> 0.69, then if there are> 3 values that go past 0.69, then the program will only highlight the 3 highest values. Meanwhile, if <3 values passed 0.69, then highlight the remainder (1 or 2).

If (column = "WASPAS")> 6.69 then
     If (row> 3) Then Highlight 3 Rows
     ElseIf (row <3) Then Highlight the Rest of Rows
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below creates a `dictionary`, adds the row index and `value` of each row in the grid to the `dictionary`, then then code gets a sorted version of the dictionary sorted by descending `value`, then colors the top three rows.

The code below uses a…

```
Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
```

`Dictionary`, To store a grids row index and the cells value. The code will loop through each row in the grid and store each rows Index and value as an item in the `dictionary.`

After the `dictionary` is filled, the code will create a new LINQ enumerable, by ordering (sorting) the items by descending value…

```
Dim sorted = From keyValuePair In dictionary
                  Order By keyValuePair.Value Descending
```

Obviously, after the sort, the highest value will be the first item in the `sorted` collection. Then the next etc.… The full example may look something like…

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)()
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvWASPAS.Rows
    If row.Cells(9).Value IsNot Nothing Then
      dictionary.Add(row.Index, CType(row.Cells(9).Value, Double))
    End If
  Next
  Dim sorted = From keyValuePair In dictionary
                           Order By keyValuePair.Value Descending
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(0).Key).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(0).Key).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(1).Key).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(1).Key).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(2).Key).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
  dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(2).Key).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

*Edit per OP comment.*

Let me see if I have this correct.

The code is given a “target” value. In this case “0.69.”

IF there are three (3) or more values that are greater “>” than the target value, THEN, only highlight the three highest values that are greater than the target value.

AND

IF there are less that three (3) values that are greater “>” than the target value, THEN only highlight those values.

If this is correct, then, a small adjustment to the current code is needed.

Since we already have ALL the values sorted from high to low, a simple solution would be to loop through the top three values and check if those values are greater than the target value. This simple change may look something like below.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)()
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvWASPAS.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
      dictionary.Add(row.Index, CType(row.Cells(0).Value, Double))
    End If
  Next
  Dim sorted = From keyValuePair In dictionary
               Order By keyValuePair.Value Descending
  Dim targetValue = 0.69
  For index = 0 To 2
    If sorted(index).Value > targetValue Then
      dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(index).Key).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
      dgvWASPAS.Rows(sorted(index).Key).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: (A) Thank you for helping me answer it. Previously asked on StackOverFlow, I've been successful in "If > 0.69", but had problems highlighting the 3 highest scores.

(B) Meanwhile the code you provided above, works fine but it only shows the highest score (regardless of the rule "if > 0.69").

I've tried combining (A & B), but it doesn't work as expected. Could you please tell me if it is possible to implement like Rule / Pseudocode? Once again, thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnG. It worked as I expected.